# Error passing object to view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

That's my relevant route:

```
Route::get('user/{username}/edit', [
    'as'   => 'user.edit',
    'uses' => "UsersController@edit"
]);
```

and the function:

```
 public function edit($username)
    {
        $user = User::where('username', '=', $username)->first();
    // dd($user);
        return View::make('user.edit' . ['user' => $user]);
    }
```

So, in another view I click a button which has the following code:

```
{{ link_to('user/'.$user->username.'/edit', 'Edit', ['class' => 'btn btn-default']) }}
```

and it leads me to the correct URL, but throws `Array to string conversion` exception for this line: `return View::make('user.edit' . ['user' => $user]);` from the **show** method. Where I dump the object, right before this line of code, it is correct, populated with values.

It is strange, because I have another method that has the exactly same implementation, but just returns to another view, and it works fine.

Any ideas why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't it be

```
return View::make('user.edit', ['user' => $user]);
```

instead of

```
return View::make('user.edit' . ['user' => $user]);
```

?

You should pass the data array, not concatenate it to the view name. Concatenating forces the array-to-string conversion.

Comment: oh, gawd... srsly... This is such a lame mistake. But dot and comma look so similar. :D

Comment: They sure do. However semicolon is the real devil in my opinion. Cheers.